# Kafka consumer groups deletion

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a large number of consumer groups created in Kafka. When I check the status most of them are with Empty status and without active consumers.

I have two questions

1. Automatic deletion of consumer group is supported in Kafka and can we configure a time period to delete the empty consumer groups?
2. Is there any specific Kafka version which supports automatic deletion of empty Consumer groups?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137375/kafka-delete-idle-consumer-group-id) might help.

Comment: You can look at the retention policy for the offsets topic. If there's no active consumers, groups get removed from that topic

Comment: @OneCricketeer I tried to find this in the kafka documentation, but was not able to find any details regarding the deletion of groups. Can you please share a link where its mentioned "offsets.retention.minutes" and deleting of groups are mentioned.

Comment: `offsets.retention.minutes` is [a broker config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_offsets.retention.minutes). The docs dont say "group is deleted"; it says its offsets expire (which cause it not to be in the topic anymore, and therefore cannot be found when queried)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To delete empty consumer groups, you have 2 options:

- Do nothing and wait `offsets.retention.minutes`. This settings defaults to 7 days. Groups without any members for this duration are automatically deleted. This mechanism exists since Kafka 0.8.2!
- Use the delete consumer group API. This can be used via the Admin API's [`deleteConsumerGroups`](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#deleteConsumerGroups-java.util.Collection-) method or the  `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` script. This API exists since Kafka 1.1.

Comment: Hi @mickael can you share documentation link for offsets.retention.minutes. I couldn't find it.

Comment: Just search that name on the Kafka website and you will find it:
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_offsets.retention.minutes